# Black screen white cursor and can't boot from live disc that I installed from just yesterday (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

So, I've decided to change to Ubuntu from Windows 7 after reformatting. Install goes smoothly,  I've set everything up, and it works for a day. It crashed when I had a full screen video, froze, so I rebooted, and now I can't get past the black screen with flashing white underscore cursor. If I wait a while, I get "Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press any key"
I've tried that, removed any boot options but the DVD drive, even tried my Windows 7 boot CD as well. Nothing boots, so I can't do anything.

This is on an Asus A52N laptop, and all I can access now is the BIOS (version K52N 217), as far as I can tell.

Comment: windows 7 disc is also not booting? check the boot device priority in BIOS

Comment: I've tried both placing the CD/DVD at a higher priority and removing boot from hdd entirely, and the result has been the same.